# React Native, problem while updating State inside useEffect from async function

Tags: reactjs, react-native, async-await, fetch-api

I'm trying the fetch data from a json API and setting it to a state. Currently using visual studio code with a pixel 4 emulator.

When I try to update my state inside of a useEffect method on the emulator's first launch or on reload, it doesn't change. If I save in vs code, the data in state updates as intended.

```
...
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {getJsonData} from './getJsonData';

const myApp = () => {
    const [state, setState] = useState({
      isLoading: true,
      data: null,
    });

    const updateState = data => {
      console.log(data); //Logs the correct Json data everytime
      setState(state => ({...state, isLoading: false, data: data}));
      console.log(state.isLoading); //Doesn't update on reload (updates only on save)
      console.log(state.data); //Same as above
    };

    useEffect(() => {
      getJsonData().then(data => updateState(data));
    }, []);

    return (
      <View>
        <Text>{state.data.title}</Text>
        <Text>{data.data.completed}</Text>
      </View>
    );
}
```

And this is the getJsonData( ) function:

```
export async function getJsonData() {
  try {
    let response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1');
    let responseJson = await response.json();
    return responseJson;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}
```

I ultimately want the state to update on the application's first run, on reload, as well as each time I call a certain reloadApp( ) function.

If the above code is not the best practice, please don't hold back to correct me as I'm just learning about states.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setState` function is asynchronous. So `console.log` immediately after `setState` will give old value but not the new value.

Also why don't you seperate the states like

```
const [isLoading,setIsLoading]=useState(true);
const [data,setData] = useState(null);
```

and set them separately so your code looks better.

in `updateState(jsonData)` you can do then

```
setIsloading(false);
setData(jsonData);
```

Comment: Oh I see, I was so focused on the log that I didn't notice the view was updating. Also, thanks for the tips.